user session closed by system
From time to time I experience user session being closed
I know I am not running out of swap space -- though it usually happens when lot of processes are running and swapspace is being used (more than 8GB swap showing allocated with htop -- i have 32 GB RAM and same for swap)
It seems to be tied to loading updates which failed. syslog extract below.
does this ring any bell for anyone ?
Thanks
--Chris
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 packagekitd[2981]: Impossible de récupérer https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/jammy-infra-security/InRelease  
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 packagekitd[2981]: Impossible de récupérer https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/jammy-infra-updates/InRelease  
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 packagekitd[2981]: Impossible de récupérer http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease  
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 packagekitd[2981]: Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 snap-store[2779849]: not handling error failed for action refresh: W: « linuxuprising-ubuntu-shutter-jammy.list.old » dans le répertoire « /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ » a été ignoré car il utilise une extension non valable#012E: Impossible de récupérer http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  #012E: Impossible de récupérer http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  #012E: Impossible de récupérer http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  #012E: Impossible de récupérer http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  #012E: Impossible de récupérer https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/dists/stable/InRelease  #012E: Impossible de récupérer https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  #012E: Impossible de récupérer https://apt.packages.shiftkey.dev/ubuntu/dists/any/InRelease  #012E: Impossible de récupérer https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease  #012E: Impossible de récupérer https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams/dists/stable/InRelease  #012E: Impossible de récupérer https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu/dists/jammy-apps-security/InRelease  #012E: Impossible de récupérer https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu/dists/jammy-apps-updates/InRelease  #012E: Impossible de récupérer https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/jammy-infra-security/InRelease  #012E: Impossible de récupérer https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu/dists/jammy-infra-updates/InRelease  #012E: Impossible de récupérer http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease  #012E: Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 systemd[1]: apt-news.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 systemd[1]: Finished Update APT News.
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 kernel: [501394.212088] audit: type=1400 audit(1720357762.230:3819): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="ubuntu_pro_esm_cache//dpkg" name="/var/lib/dpkg/arch" pid=2781693 comm="dpkg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 kernel: [501394.239863] audit: type=1400 audit(1720357762.258:3820): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="ubuntu_pro_esm_cache//dpkg" name="/var/lib/dpkg/arch" pid=2781695 comm="dpkg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 snapd[2247]: storehelpers.go:923: cannot refresh:
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 snapd[2247]: snap has no updates available: "bare", "canonical-livepatch", "chromium", "core20", "core22", "core24", "cups", "firefox", "gnome-3-38-2004", "gnome-42-2204", "gnome-46-2404", "gtk-common-themes", "mesa-2404", "snap-store", "snapd", "snapd-desktop-integration"
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 snapd[2247]: snap not found: "gnome-extension-manager"
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 snapd[2247]: storehelpers.go:923: cannot refresh:
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 snapd[2247]: snap has no updates available: "bare", "canonical-livepatch", "chromium", "core20", "core22", "core24", "cups", "firefox", "gnome-3-38-2004", "gnome-42-2204", "gnome-46-2404", "gtk-common-themes", "mesa-2404", "snap-store", "snapd", "snapd-desktop-integration"
Jul  7 15:09:22 x390 snapd[2247]: snap not found: "gnome-extension-manager"
Jul  7 15:09:23 x390 kernel: [501395.079833] audit: type=1400 audit(1720357763.098:3821): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="ubuntu_pro_esm_cache//dpkg" name="/var/lib/dpkg/arch" pid=2781704 comm="dpkg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jul  7 15:09:23 x390 systemd[1]: esm-cache.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul  7 15:09:23 x390 systemd[1]: Finished Update the local ESM caches.
Jul  7 15:09:23 x390 systemd[1]: esm-cache.service: Consumed 1.052s CPU time.
Jul  7 15:09:23 x390 PackageKit: get-updates transaction /2266_edaeccee from uid 1000 finished with success after 1598ms
Jul  7 15:09:24 x390 systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 128...
[----- > etc]


I can not see anything failed in what you posted.
